Apm transaction for Kafka using node and nest.js
I need to monitor my Kafka events in my node application with nest.js.
Apm doesn't have support yet, so I did it this way, very simply, using NestInterceptor to create a transaction in APM.
Would you have any suggestions on the code?
My Main File
main.ts

  const apmMiddleware = app.get(APM_MIDDLEWARE);
  const globalInterceptors = [
    app.get(ApmHttpUserContextInterceptor),
    app.get(ApmErrorInterceptor),
    new ApmInterceptor(app.get(ApmService)),
  ];

My intercecptor
apm.interceptor.ts

import {
  Injectable,
  NestInterceptor,
  ExecutionContext,
  CallHandler,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ApmService } from '@mitz-it/elastic-apm-nest';

@Injectable()
export class ApmInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(private readonly apmService: ApmService) {}

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    if (context.getType() === 'rpc') {
      const rpcContext = context.switchToRpc();

      const pattern = context.getType();
      const topic = rpcContext.getContext()?.args[2];

      const payload = rpcContext.getData();

      const transaction = this.apmService.startTransaction(
        `${pattern} ${topic}`,
        'request',
      );

      if (payload) transaction.addLabels({ data: JSON.stringify(payload) });

      transaction.end();

      return next.handle();
    }
  }
}


